# Thread Ordering Service isn't enabled

Tags: c++, multithreading, winapi

I am studying the Thread Ordering Service of Windows. So, I have written the following code to test how TOS works really? But it doesn't work and it gives me an error.

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <process.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <avrt.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#pragma comment(lib, "Avrt.lib")
#define _100NS_IN_1MS 10000

unsigned __stdcall Thread1(void* arg_list)
{
    for (size_t i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        std::cout << "\tHello from Thread1, Repeat #" << i + 1 << std::endl;
        SwitchToThread();
    }
    return 0;
}

unsigned __stdcall Thread2(void* arg_list)
{
    for (size_t i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        std::cout << "\tHello from Thread2, Repeat #" << i + 1 << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}


int main()
{
    HANDLE handle_context = NULL;
    LARGE_INTEGER period, timeout;
    GUID guid = { 0 };
    BOOL result;

    period.QuadPart = Int32x32To64(_100NS_IN_1MS, 1000);   // 1 second
    timeout.QuadPart = Int32x32To64(_100NS_IN_1MS, 10000); // 10 seconds

    result = AvRtCreateThreadOrderingGroup(&handle_context, &period, &guid, &timeout);
    
    if (result != TRUE)
    {
        printf("Error creating group (%d)\n", GetLastError());
        return 1;
    }

    HANDLE handle_thread1 = (HANDLE)_beginthreadex(NULL, 0, Thread1, NULL, CREATE_SUSPENDED, NULL);
    HANDLE handle_thread2 = (HANDLE)_beginthreadex(NULL, 0, Thread2, NULL, CREATE_SUSPENDED, NULL);
    
    AvRtJoinThreadOrderingGroup(&handle_thread1, &guid, FALSE);
    AvRtJoinThreadOrderingGroup(&handle_thread2, &guid, FALSE);

    if (handle_thread1 == NULL && handle_thread2 == NULL)
    {
        return -1;
    }

    ResumeThread(handle_thread1);
    ResumeThread(handle_thread2);

    int recieve1 = WaitForSingleObject(handle_thread1, INFINITE);
    int recieve2 = WaitForSingleObject(handle_thread2, INFINITE);

    CloseHandle(handle_thread1);
    CloseHandle(handle_thread2);
}
```

When I run the above program, it gives me the following error:

> Error creating group (1058)
> 1058 (0x422)
>
> The service cannot be started, either because it is disabled or
> because it has no enabled devices associated with it.

What should I do now? I am using Windows 10.

Comment: The documentation (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/procthread/thread-ordering-service) states: 'The thread ordering service is off by default and must be started by the user'. Did you start the service?

Comment: Be very careful with this.  The legitimate use cases for the TOS are extremely limited and the ways you can write awful, terrible, evil code are almost limitless.  This is not a tool you pick up to solve random programming problems or that you should consider in general architectures.  It is almost certainly not the correct solution for all but the most niche and considered cases.

Comment: How should I enable this service though? @Zaiborg

Comment: @Cayoot Unfortunately i have no idea. A quick search did not yield promising results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The links [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/procthread/thread-ordering-service) and [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/avrt/nf-avrt-avrtcreatethreadorderinggroup), explain that Windows *Thread Ordering Service* is not on by default:

> The thread ordering service ***is off by default and must be started by
> the user***. While the thread ordering service is running, it is
> activated every 5 seconds to check whether there is a new request,
> even if the system is idle. This prevents the system from sleeping for
> longer than 5 seconds, causing the system to consume more power. If
> energy efficiency is critical to the application, it is better not to
> use the thread ordering service and instead allow the system scheduler
> to manage execution of threads.

Use cases and other discussion are also discussed and code snippets are provided in some of the other links (see 2nd link above.) Following is an example:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <avrt.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#pragma comment(lib, "Avrt.lib")

#define _100NS_IN_1MS 10000

int main( void )
{
    HANDLE hContext = NULL;
    LARGE_INTEGER period, timeout;
    GUID guid = { 0 };
    BOOL bRes;

    period.QuadPart = Int32x32To64(_100NS_IN_1MS, 1000);   // 1 second
    timeout.QuadPart = Int32x32To64(_100NS_IN_1MS, 10000); // 10 seconds

    bRes = AvRtCreateThreadOrderingGroup( 
            &hContext,
            &period,
            &guid,
            &timeout );

    if( bRes != TRUE )
    {
        printf("Error creating group (%d)\n", GetLastError());
            return 1;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I have problem with enabling this service in windows 10. I don't know how should I enable it. Can you explain to me?

Comment: @Cayoot - That will entail some searching/reading on [UAC](https://www.digitalcitizen.life/how-change-user-account-control-uac-levels), making sure you are running with sufficient privilege, etc.  Windows 10 has introduced many new controls to tighten/restrict easy access to almost everything.

Comment: I run the program with sufficient privilege, but I get the same error. I check msconfig -> services too, but I couldn't find out thread ordering services there.

Comment: @Cayoot - Have you already run the example code, i.e. built a project and included the `avrt.lib` file?  What exactly was the error message?

Comment: It said: "The service cannot be started, either because it is disabled or because it has no enabled devices associated with it." I don't know how should I run the service. I search a lot but I couldn't find out any information.

Comment: @Cayoot -  Is this a company PC configured by an IT department, or a personal PC?

Comment: It is a personal PC bro.

Comment: @Cayoot - Its is going to take some more reading and experimenting.  As an aside, the PC I have access to at this point is not configured to allow me anything more than what you are seeing on yours.  (IT just _updated_ everything, and my local admin was affected.)  Once I get that back, I will look at this again, but until then I am stuck .

Comment: Okay. I will wait for the result of your test.

Comment: @Cayoot - I do not know when I will be able to dig into this, so it may not be soon.  But if/when I learn anything, I will make comments and edits